# Why is the nRF24L01 not working with Arduino Esplora?

Tags: spi, nrf24l01+, rf, arduino-esplora

I am working on a remote control car from an Arduino Esplora board and the Mega 2650 Board. My problem lies with the Esplora board as the nRF does not transmit like it is supposed to or does not even transmit at all.

I am using the [`pingpair_test.ino`](https://github.com/maniacbug/RF24/blob/master/tests/pingpair_test/pingpair_test.pde) from the [RF24](https://github.com/maniacbug/RF24) library to make sure the transceiver is working, and when I try to transmit on the serial monitor, I get the following output:

```
Configuration = t

STATUS = 0x00 RX_DR=0 TX_DS=0 MAX_RT=0 RX_P_NO=0 TX_FULL=0 

RX_ADDR_P0-1 = 0x0000000000 0x0000000000

RX_ADDR_P2-5 = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00

TX_ADDR = 0x0000000000

RX_PW_P0-6 = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00

EN_AA = 0x00

EN_RXADDR = 0x00

RF_CH = 0x00

RF_SETUP = 0x00

CONFIG = 0x00

DYNPD/FEATURE = 0x00 0x00

Data Rate = 1MBPS

Model = nRF24L01

CRC Length = Disabled

PA Power = PA_MIN

Now sending length 4...No responses received. Are interrupts connected?
```

I have no idea what any of this means besides the interrupts part.

Even using `interrupts();` the Arduino Esplora still refuses to send data. I am sure my wiring is correct because the status light on the nRF is on and I triple checked all of the SPI pins.

On the Esplora:

- CE = 0
- CSN = 1

On the Mega:

- CE = 51
- CSN = 50

I have a fritzing sketch [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B54AEA44CB029F51!53123&authkey=!APUwJhmiNuUa6d8&ithint=file%2Czip) for those who want to see my wiring.

Comment: Bad wiring, check it three times and verify you are using the right pins. Another option is that your module is broken. Currently the library can't even detect the module (at all, like totally 0).

Comment: You may not be using the IRQ pin.   Mind posting your code so we can comment/troubleshoot?

Comment: @tr4nc3 - I have edited the question, and added a link to the actual `pingpair.pde` file. However, one thing that strikes me as odd is that the quoted output has a misspelling in `recieved`. However, the [actual code line](https://github.com/maniacbug/RF24/blob/master/tests/pingpair_test/pingpair_test.pde#L310) does not... How is that possible?

Comment: Uhh, also update your library it's ancient, either from the IDE of from https://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/.

Comment: @Greenonline Yeah I had to manually type the output because copy-paste wasn't working. Idk why.

Comment: As for the module being broken it isn't because I tried it on another board. And I repeatedly checked my wiring so I am 99.9% sure it's right.

Comment: is there a way you could post a picture of your wiring because i'm having the same problem as you

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more [reputation](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), [you will be able to post comments](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm going to delete this answer. Thanks for your understanding and cooperation!

Comment: How much voltage are you supplying to the nRF24? It must be 3.3v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny you should ask, I have been playing with nRF24 for a while, and was thinking of trying out my Esplora. There are however a few problems, which have postponed this (read: can't be arsed).

1. Pins. You need access to the SPI pins + 2 other pins. On the code you linked to, it's 8 and 9. Which won't work on an Esplora: D9 is not broken out, and D8 is CARD_CS. Better leave that alone. Your best bet would be to use the ICSP header and the two orange TinkerKit pins, D11 & D3.

**[UPDATE]** Also, the RF24 library uses `D2` for IRQ, which is going to be slightly inconvenient on an Esplora, as this pin isn't broken out either. TMRh20 doesn't use an IRQ pin. Neither does Mirf.

[image: ICSP Header]

[image]

2. As you can see, the Esplora is on 5V, which could [give the nRF24 module a headache](https://www.google.com/search?q=nrf24%20max%20voltage). You'll have to step that down to 3.3. Way too much work for me, but then again I'm lazy.
3. If you're planning on using the screen, the ICSP header is kind of in an awkward place. I've tried fitting regular cables under the screen, and all I've got for my pains was a big dose of what the heck.
4. Stand-alone power. If you're planning to use the Esplora as a standalone, you'll need a battery and a voltage stepper. So in the end, you could use the voltage of the battery for the nRF24 module, and the 5V output from the stepper for the Esplora. More work, grrr.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your output either you have a wrong wiring or, more probably, you need a capacitor between the nRF24 positive and negative pins: anything between 10uF and 100uF will do.